# Python Invalid Syntax error for function Default Argument

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code, I don't see any issue with this.

```
def test_methopd(async=False):
    pass
```

When I import the module I am getting following error.

```
$ python3 -c "import test"
 File "/Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/ctc/code/ci-cd-framework/atf/clients/test.py", line 1
    def test_methopd(async=False):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code works perfectly fine with **Python 3.4.9** however gives error with **Python 3.7.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Python 3.7 `async` is a reserved word which cannot be used as an identifier (such as a parameter name)

PEP describing this change: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#deprecation-plans

> **Depreciation Plans**
>
> `async` and `await` names will be softly deprecated in CPython 3.5 and
> 3.6. In 3.7 we will transform them to proper keywords.

This is also reflected in the online docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords